# How to add a custom event to a blazor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, blazor

I have created a tab control in my blazor server side application, [based on a tutorial](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/). The control works fine, however I want to be able to tell, when the active page was changed. Therefore I added a event to the code:

```
internal void ActivatePage(TabPage page)
{
    OnTabSelectionChanged();
    ActivePage = page;
}

public delegate void TabSelectionChangedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
public event TabSelectionChangedEventHandler TabSelectionChanged;

protected virtual void OnTabSelectionChanged()
{
    TabSelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Now I want to do the following in my blazor component, which uses the control:

```
<TabControl @TabSelectionChanged="MyFunction">
    <TabPage Text="tab #1">
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
    <TabPage Text="tab #2"> 
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
    <TabPage Text="tab #3"> 
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
</TabControl>
```

How would one achieve this?

Comment: That's quite windows formsy-flavored; might be more in keeping to use something like `[Parameter] public EventCallback<YourEventArgsClassHere> OnXxx { get; set; }` and then users of your component can send some delegate that takes a YourEventArgsClasshere as a parameter..

Comment: @CaiusJard I have looked into EventCallbacks, every example I have found was done with existing 'built-in' event such as `OnClick`.  How would a EventCallback property look like for my case above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How would a EventCallback property look like for my case above?

I was thinking not hugely dissimilar to what you have

```
@code{

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TabPage> TabPageActivated { get; set; }

    internal async Task ActivatePage(TabPage page)
    {
        ActivePage = page;
        await TabPageActivated.InvokeAsyc(page);
    }

}
```

And to do the following in the blazor whatever, which uses the control:

```
<TabControl @TabPageActivated="MyFunction">
    <TabPage Text="tab #1">
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
    <TabPage Text="tab #2"> 
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
    <TabPage Text="tab #3"> 
        <!-- content -->
    </TabPage>
</TabControl>

@code{
    private async Task MyFunction(TabPage t){
      ...
    }
}
```

If you don't want parameter TabPage, then more like:

```
public EventCallback TabPageActivated { get; set; }
...

    await TabPageActivated.InvokeAsyc();
...

private async Task MyFunction(){
```

Comment: Hehe,I was just about to write my own answer :)
Thanks!

Comment: One note: I think instead of the `?` operator, one has to use the `HasDelegate`. At least I get an error otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copypasta typo! It won't crash anything if you InvokeAsync and there isn't a delegate, and EventCallback can't be null because it's a class level instance of a struct so acquires a default value even if not explicity set, but HasDelegate can be useful for detecting if it's been set for some other reason

Comment: I had to leave the "@" out in front of the TabPageActivated when hooking up the event in the parent control. Probably because I am on ASP.NET 7, which was not released yet when you posted that answer.